# Virtualbox causing 16.04 to freeze completely

Tags: virtualbox

I'm sure I've missed a step somewhere in configuring my machine to run Virtualbox, but when trying to boot a new VM (Ubuntu MATE) my host machine completely locks up. No GUI, no terminal, no SSH. My only recourse is a hard restart.

The host machine is running 16.04 LTS on a Gen 10 HP Proliant server and all packages should be up to date.

I've checked the MD5 hash on the iso. I've given the VM 2 gigs of memory, made sure it's using the correct type of pointing device and that it's booting from the .iso first.

I've reviewed several guides on installing Virtualbox and setting up VMs and I don't feel like I'm doing anything wrong, but obviously something is amiss. I'm just not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to Virtualbox-5.2 and disabling USB support for the guest OS has solved this issue.

Comment: You might be able to get USB support working if you install [the VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) for your version of VirtualBox. It adds USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 support to VirtualBox.